# Why v-for in template is updating just when the input text change?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have this code in vuejs but the for in the template is not updating.
it change when add some data in input text but I want to update the list in the @click

https://jsfiddle.net/nqtg9vq2/

```
methods: {
    addModule:function(){
        var size = Object.keys( this.modules ).length;
        this.modules[size] = {
            enumerate: '1.1',
            name: 'test',
            description: 'test d',
            type: 'module',
            criteria: {}
        };
        console.log(this.modules);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Vue.js can't detect a new property in an object. See https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Change-Detection-Caveats

You can use Vue.set():

```
var size = Object.keys( this.modules ).length;
        Vue.set(this.modules,size,{
            enumerate: '1.1',
            name: 'test',
            description: 'test d',
            type: 'module',
            criteria: {}
        });
```

Comment: Or change `this.modules` to an array and use `this.modules.push({...})`.

Comment: Yes @Botje you can use an array, but if EdgarAlejandro prefers an object...

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you're running into an object change detection caveat as defined in the vue.js documentation. Specifically, you seem to be adding a new object property that didn't exist before and so the change isn't being detected.

Here is a possible fix:

```
methods: {
    addModule:function(){
        var size = Object.keys( this.modules ).length;
        this.modules[size] = {
            enumerate: '1.1',
            name: 'test',
            description: 'test d',
            type: 'module',
            criteria: {}
        };
        this.modules = Object.assign({}, this.modules);
        console.log(this.modules);
    }
}
```

The added line will act as an assigned to a cloned version of the original object. Since this cloned object is effectively a separate object altogether, the associated changes will be forced to be detected.

Be warned, however, that deep cloning will require additional work if needed.